# Define custome routes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, custom-routes

I wants to process multiple url segments with single controller and function
here is example:

1) https://www.somedomain.com/abc and

2) https://www.somedomain.com/xyz/abc

how can i define the routes in one line, so both request can be performed with single function

like here i need to define two routes 
get "/:static_page", to: "SomeController#action_name"

get "/:static_page/:second_option", to: "SomeController#action_name"

But how can i define in one line? or can manage this approach any other way.

Comment: Is the first segment always going to the same?  For example, is the route always going to be `/xyz/:something`  where `/xyz/` is always the same? Or are both parts of the url going to change?

Comment: yes, both part going to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called a catch-all and is a superb way to shoot yourself in the foot.

```
match '*path', to: 'some#action_name'
```

You have to pay really close attention to ordering (declare it last) as it will catch any other routes that match the pattern - in this case everything.

Its also a huge source of bugs as Rails now will take any request thrown at it and pass it to your controller instead of raising a routing error. Like for example those pesky bots that are trolling your site for WordPress vulnerabilites.

If you really need some additional non-restful routes just declare them normally instead of funneling everything into what is going to become a monstrosity of a controller.

Comment: yes, above solution with via method solve my problem. I just mentioned the match "*path", via: "get", to: 'profile#index' in last of Rails.application.routes.draw do block so none of existing path's are override.

Comment: Its a solution but not a very good one. If you have any other alternative - take it.

Comment: yes, thanks for your suggestions, you are right, it can be vulnerable  but in my case it is ok as i have not used any API services and not created any API, also no other solution i have this time.